# Servlet para no volver a la pagina anterior

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hola estoy intentando que la informacion de la pagina anterior(me muestras el menu con los datos cargados) al login ya no aparesca y me redireccione a el login

ya logre que no entre sin un login pero al momento de volver atras la pagina me carga la informacion por mas que le halla dado cerrar sesion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por ahora estoy utilizando este script

history.forward();

no me deja volver a la pagina anterior , pero si me muestra por un milisegundo de la informacion, quisiera saber si hay otra forma sin usar history.forward();